# Is there a standard for an 84-key UK keyboard?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout, key-codes

---

I got a new 84-key keyboard which claims to be made for the UK for its compactness and realize that the forward slash and the vertical slash are not found on it, although they are labelled and are accessible via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>.

The key which is labelled with them produce the `~` and `#` characters.

Is there a standard 84-key UK keyboard with a standard or recognized set of key labels, that covers most of the keys an advanced PC user (Linux) might want?

I'm not adverse to reprogramming Linux to set the characters, but I want to be sure I'm building on the right foundation.

Comment: If it has UK layout it should work with any OS correctly set for UK layout. Number of keys is immaterial as long as key combos also work. Which OS are you running and which keyboard layout have you set?

Comment: @ChanganAuto I'm running Linux. Does Linux have a command to identify the type of keyboard plugged in?
It says Xinmeng XM-RF84 and is distributed under a brand name manbasnake.
Product implementation standard number: GB/T 14081-2010

Comment: Linux is the kernel, not the OS. The actual OS (Debian, RHEL, Ubuntu, Manjaro, ...) matters! And even more important is the DE (Desktop Environment) on top of the base system because that's what sets and manages the user inputs. And there's no such thing as "identify the type of keyboard", *per se*, and it doesn't matter. The point is, as always, to select the correct layout - it's wrong whenever the characters in your screen don't match what's printed in the keys - which is independent of the actual keyboard hardware/peripheral detecting (...)

Comment: (...) if it works it has been correctly recognized by the OS, as expected, obviously. Then it a matter of selecting the matching keyboard **layout**, something that is your, not the OS' or the DE's, job.

Answer (score 1):

You have not stated which Linux-variant (distro, distribution) you're using.

Example: Ubuntu...

- Hit the win-key, begin to type `Settings` and the corresponding icon
  will appear, click on it.
- Find `Region & Language` and `Input sources`;
- Note the  (eye) icon, click on it and you will be presented with
  the actual keyboard layout.
- The `+` right below the eye will present a list with the most common
  keyboard layouts,
- and the `⠇` (three dot) option last in the list will allow to select
  from a longer list, and also a multitude of `other` layouts.

Do explore, hopefully you will find something that suits your needs better.

*If your distro isn't Ubuntu, you will most likely find something similar in that distro's settings.*

Comment: I use both Linux and Windows. For Linux EXWM is my primary desktop, but I also switch KDE when necessary